# How to do client side validations if some text boxes are generated dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm working on a form which has this add button, if the button is clicked a text box is foing to generate and i have a minus button to cancel it.

my problem is i have to work on client side validations in this page

the code i used to generate new text boxes is

```
i = 0;
var counter = 2;

$("#addButton").click(function () {
    optionCount++;
i++;


var newTextBoxDiv = $(document.createElement('div'))
     .attr("id", 'TextBoxDiv'+i);
   newTextBoxDiv.after().html('<label>Option : </label>' +
      '<input type="text" class="add_input" name="textbox'  + counter + '"   id="textbox' + counter + '" > <input type="button" class="rem_img minusclick" id="removeButton'+i+'"  alt="Remove"  title="Remove" onclick="RemoveButton(\''+i+'\',\''+counter+'\')">');

 newTextBoxDiv.appendTo("#TextBoxesGroup");
    optionIds.push(counter);
    counter++;
```

The validation is to be done after clicking the submit button. and i need to display an error message beside each empty text box(that is generated by clicking add button)

im confused where to start and what exactly i have to do for this
Please help..

Comment: you Haven't mentioned about your validation part?

Comment: provide us a jsfiddle mate

Comment: sorry.. the validations must be done when i click on submit button

Comment: @Outlooker im sorry i dont know what's jsfiddle is..

Comment: provide us with a slight demo.Use http://jsfiddle.net/ to create a demo mate..alteast add your html part in your question.

Comment: when you want the validation to happen click on addButotn or removeButton?

Comment: its a form and i need to validate after clicking submit button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I add onchange method textbox;

```
i = 0;
var counter = 2;

$("#addButton").click(function () {
    optionCount++;
i++;


var newTextBoxDiv = $(document.createElement('div'))
     .attr("id", 'TextBoxDiv'+i);
   newTextBoxDiv.after().html('<label>Option : </label>' +
      '<input type="text" onchange="Validate(this,\"ValueControl\")" class="add_input" name="textbox'  + counter + '"   id="textbox' + counter + '" > <input type="button" class="rem_img minusclick" id="removeButton'+i+'"  alt="Remove"  title="Remove" onclick="RemoveButton(\''+i+'\',\''+counter+'\')">');

 newTextBoxDiv.appendTo("#TextBoxesGroup");
    optionIds.push(counter);
    counter++;
```

Create This function;

```
 function Validate(elementObject,validType){
            if(validType=="ValueControl"){
                if($(elementObject).val()==''){
                    $(elementObject).css("background-color","#000000");
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for the help but i dont know why its not working for me

Comment: I think generate attribute for your idea. And use for solving problem..

For example; <input type='text' name='test' validate='valuecontrol,emailcontrol,atcontrol' class='x y validate' onchange='Validate(this);'>

Comment: it worked with just a little modification.. thanks for the idea